# Count $k$-subsets with at least $d>1$ different elements (pairwise)

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

The problem of counting the number of $k$-subsets in a set of size $n$ is well known.
The answer is ${n \choose k}$.

But here, I want $k$-subsets with the property that any two of them have at least $d$ different elements.

If we take the set $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ ($n=6$), we have 15 4-subsets. (no need to enumerate them.) 
If you want those subsets to have at least 2 different elements pairwise, then the maximum number I could find is 3. ($\{1, 2, 3, 4\}, \{1, 2, 5, 6\}, \{3, 4, 5, 6\}$).

I am working with neuronal networks (kind of), and I want to represent symbols with $k$ neurons. But to ensure some difference between representation, I would like these subsets to be different enough (typically $d = k/2$). We also have $n >>k$.

Any (lower or upper) bound would be helpful. For example an approximation could use ${n/d \choose k/d}$ with proper rounding, but that is a bit rough.

Any simpler solution is also welcome, eg:

- $k$ even, $d=k/2$, $n=0 \mod k$
- $d=2$
- etc.

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Your question might be related to "constant weight codes" (a concept studied by coding theory); this [page](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/codes/Andw.htm) might provide some information too.

Comment: @PeterKošinár : The link is broken to me. I will have a look to weight codes.

Comment: That's it, definitely. I am looking for $A(n,d,k)$, which cannot be computed but only approximated... Too bad.
Do we have an idea of the increase of this function, something in big $O$ notation maybe ?

Comment: Just for reference: [corrected link](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/codes/Andw.html)